# CMD + W doesn't work anymore on macOS Mojave

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

After installing [the .dotfiles](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles) on my new Macbook (Mojave) the keyboard combination <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> to close tabs or windows stopped working system wide.

I found out that when I press <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> it works. But this is not my desired solution.

Any suggestions on how I can get <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> to close tabs or windows?

Comment: HI, Welcome to Apple.SE! What is the close tab's shortcut in File Menu of say, Safari?

Comment: Hi, thanks! In Safari its not set, but in Chrome its CMD + W.

Comment: And if you remove the someone else's dotfiles you installed?

Comment: I tried to remove all the dotfiles and rebooted but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by installing the dotfiles again. Still don't know what caused the problem…

Answer (score 1):

This is a decade old, but suggests it has something to do with the
Omnibox flag:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=45928#c22